# send data in location.replace with post method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open new page by javascript and send data to that new page , i used this `location.replace("test.php?data=123")` but problem is I want my **data** be hidden, I know I should use post but i can't use post with **location.replace** do you have any idea?

Comment: Send it with base64_encode and then, you recieve that and base it back base64_decode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.location.replace - POST version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911053/window-location-replace-post-version)

Comment: You can save it in session, cookie, loca.storage, and use that on other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the session-storage API

You can save any data as string (the key and the value must also be a string)

#### Old page:

```js
sessionStorage.setItem('data', '123')
```

#### new page:

```js
const data = sessionStorage.getItem('data')
data === '123'
```